# Create random data from custom type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following custom type defined

```
data Tree = Empty | Node Tree Tree
```

I want to create random `Tree`s with a given number of nodes `n` that I can then pass to another function which calculates the depth of the tree

```
depth :: Tree -> Int
depth Empty = 0
depth Node t1 t2 = (maximum [depth t1, depth t2]) + 1
```

Which is the easiest way to achieve this?

EDIT: I have tried with an approach similar to that of Alec in an answer below, which returns a random `IO Tree`. However, there are several other functions I need to pass this random `Tree`s to, over which I have no control. These require an argument of type `Tree`, not `IO Tree` so this solution doesn`t quite work for my purposes.

Comment: This is I think a library recommendation question, or at least the answer is: use `smallcheck`, or `quickcheck`, or something else shinier. If you want to do this task yourself as a learning experience, then I would ask what you've tried so far and where you're stuck

Comment: If you create a truly random tree, how will you know what the depth of the tree is so that you'll know if `depth` is returning the correct answer? You want *deterministic* input for your tests.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a simple recursive problem. The only complication is that getting a random number requires either threading through explicitly a generator, or working within `IO`. For simplicity, I'll stick with the latter.

```
import System.Random

data Tree = Empty | Node Tree Tree

-- | Generate a tree of the given size
arbitraryTree :: Int -> IO Tree
arbitraryTree treeSize
  | treeSize <= 1 = pure Empty  -- base case, tree of size 1
  | otherwise = do
      leftSize <- randomRIO (0,treeSize - 1)
      let rightSize = treeSize - 1 - leftSize

      leftSubtree <- arbitraryTree leftSize
      rightSubtree <- arbitraryTree rightSize

      pure (Node leftSubtree rightSubtree)
```

Comment: This looks quite like what I want,the only problem is that my `depth` function requires a `Tree` not a `IO Tree`. Which is the correct way to work around this?

Comment: In `GHCi` (or in your `main` function's `do`-block) `trees <- Control.Monad.replicateM numberOfTrees (arbitraryTree myDepth)`. Then, `trees :: [Tree]`.

Answer (score 1):

[QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) is your friend. Now is a great time to begin learning it.

You asked about generating random trees. In QuickCheck terms, we generate *arbitrary* trees using the typeclass [`Arbitrary`](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#18).

```
class Arbitrary a where
  arbitrary   :: Gen a
  coarbitrary :: a -> Gen b -> Gen b
```

[`Gen`](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#13) is a typeclass for test data generators.

> #### Test Data Generators: The Type Gen
>
> Test data is produced by test data generators. QuickCheck defines
>   default generators for most types, but you can use your own with
>   `forAll`, and will need to define your own generators for any new
>   types you introduce.
>
> Generators have types of the form `Gen a`; this is a generator for
>   values of type `a`. The type `Gen` is a monad, so Haskell's `do`
>   syntax and standard monadic functions can be used to define
>   generators.
>
> Generators are built up on top of the function
>
> ```
> choose :: Random a => (a, a) -> Gen a
> ```
>
> which makes a random choice of a value from an interval, with a
>   uniform distribution. For example, to make a random choice between the
>   elements of a list, use
>
> ```
> do i <- choose (0, length xs-1)
>    return (xs !! i)
> ```

In your question, you say you want to generate trees with a certain number of nodes. An `Arbitrary` instance for that is

```
instance Arbitrary Tree where
  arbitrary = sized tree'
    where tree' 0 = return Empty
          tree' n | n > 0 = do
            lsize <- choose (0, n - 1)
            l <- tree' lsize
            r <- tree' (n - lsize - 1)
            return $ Node l r
```

This instance respects an external size parameter thanks to [`sized`](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#15).

> #### The Size of Test Data
>
> Test data generators have an implicit `size` parameter; quickCheck
>   begins by generating small test cases, and gradually increases the
>   size as testing progresses. Different test data generators interpret
>   the size parameter in different ways: some ignore it, while the list
>   generator, for example, interprets it as an upper bound on the length
>   of generated lists. You are free to use it as you wish to control your
>   own test data generators. You can obtain the value of the size
>   parameter using
>
> ```
> sized :: (Int -> Gen a) -> Gen a
> ```
>
> `sized g` calls `g`, passing it the current size as a parameter. For
>   example, to generate natural numbers in the range 0 to n, use
>
> ```
> sized $ \n -> choose (0, n)
> ```

The internal `tree'` generator takes the number of nodes remaining and creates a tree by creating `Empty` when the parameter is zero or else creating a `Node` whose left subtree has size between 0 and `n` - 1 (less 1 to account for the node itself) and whose right subtree gets the remaining elements.

Say you have a function

```
nodes Empty = 0
nodes (Node l r) = 1 + nodes l + nodes r
```

and we want to see that it correctly counts nodes in 10-node trees. After defining the property

```
prop_nodes_count = forAll (resize 10 arbitrary) (\t -> nodes t == 10)
```

we successfully test it in GHCi with

```
λ> quickCheck prop_nodes_count
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

The code above uses `resize` to force the size of the generated trees.

To demonstrate that you can generate a pure list of trees, *i.e.*, `[Tree]` rather than `IO [Tree]`, we’ll use a simple standin.

```
print_trees :: [Tree] -> IO ()
print_trees = print
```

Ultimately, QuickCheck generators are random and therefore stateful, so generating them from your `main` action is an easy approach.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  trees <- sample' (resize 0 arbitrary)
  print_trees $ take 1 trees
  trees' <- sample' (resize 1 arbitrary)
  print_trees $ take 1 trees'
  trees'' <- sample' (resize 2 arbitrary)
  print_trees $ take 2 trees''
```

Doing the work here is `sample'` that has type `Gen a -> IO [a]`. That is, when run inside an `IO` action, `sample'` produces a list of whatever it is you want to generate, arbitrary trees in this case. The related function `sample` has type `Show a => Gen a -> IO ()`, which means it goes ahead an prints the generated test data.

The output of the above program after adding `deriving Show` to your definition of `Tree` is

```
[Empty]
[Node Empty Empty]
[Node (Node Empty Empty) Empty,Node Empty (Node Empty Empty)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! This problem is best approached in two parts: generating a list of `Tree`s with the required amount of nodes, and then selecting one value at random from that list.

We'll start with the first problem: given a number *n*, generate a list of all `Tree`s with *n* `Node`s. But how would we do this? Let's try out a few simple cases for small *n*s. For *n* = 0, we have only one choice: `Empty`. (From now on, I'll abbreviate `Node` and `Empty` as `N` and `E` respectfully to reduce the amount of typing.) For *n* = 1, we also have only one choice: `N E E`. For *n* = 2, we have two cases, which we can generate from the *n* = 1 case by replacing one `E` with `N E E`:

```
N (N E E) E
N E (N E E)
```

For *n* = 3, we can repeat the same procedure, substituting each `E` in turn in each case with `N E E` to find all the possible places we can add an extra node:

```
N (N (N E E) E) E
N (N E (N E E)) E
N (N E E) (N E E)
N E (N (N E E) E)
N E (N E (N E E))
```

We can do this via a recursive function:

```
allWithNum :: Int -> [Tree]
allWithNum 0 = [Empty]
allWithNum n = nub $ concatMap subWithNode (allWithNum $ n-1)
  where
    subWithNode = fmap snd . filter fst . go False
      where
        go False Empty = [(True,Node Empty Empty),(False,Empty)]
        go True  Empty = [(True,Empty)]
        go hasSubdNode (Node x y) = do
            (subdX, newX) <- go hasSubdNode x
            (subdY, newY) <- go subdX y
            return (subdY, Node newX newY)
```

(Note that this uses `nub` from `Data.List`, and also requires `Tree` to have an `Eq` instance.)

Most of the work here is done in `go`, which moves along a `Tree` substituting `Node Empty Empty` into each `Empty` in turn, keeping track in its first argument of whether a substitution has been made yet.

Now for the second problem: how do we choose a random element from this list? This may be done using the functions in the [`System.Random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html) module from the `random` package, by using `choose (0, length_of_list)` to choose an index and then getting the value at that index using `(!!)`.